# Forcebuild CruiseControl.net from remote command line

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Is there a command line switch to forcebuild cruisecontrol.net remotely. I am trying to avoid going to cctray and forcebuilding it manually every morning. It seems I have to create custom hook on the CruiseControl server by creating my own custom web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building every morning, why not set up a schedule trigger instead?

UPDATE BASED ON NEW INFORMATION:
If your Power Shell script can be modified to modify an internally accessible web page (update a time stamp text in the HTML), then you can use the urlTrigger

Comment: Reason being is I have a database powershell script that needed to be run before the forcebuild. So the forcebuild is dependent on the database powershell script completing. I have looked at the cctray source code on how the forcebuild is called which is through .net remoting. In CruiseControl java side they have the JMX webservice which is what I need in CruiseControl.net. Right now I am looking at the alternative of calling forcebuild through .net remoting in powershell or cmd line.

Comment: Can you point me to a documentation for URL Trigger. I tried googling to no avail but manage to see some threads discussing about URL Trigger.

Comment: So you are saying I should create a dummy HTML page and get the url trigger to point to that page. Let my powershell script update the timestamp on that html page then URL trigger. looks like it might work.

Comment: @odez213, That is my suggestion. If the time stamp for the file is not enough to trigger the build, you may need to inject the time stamp INTO the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2):

What about writing a Powershell Wrapper around ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.dll? We do something very similar in a project we call CruiseHydra which emulates the ability to split multiple tasks across several build servers. I have attempted to extract the portions that should be relevant to you here. Please note that I have not tested this exact code, our library wraps this deep in its own abstraction, but the jist of it is here:

```
using ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote;

public ForceBuild(String ServerAddress, String projectToExecute)
{
  RemoteCruiseManagerFactory rcmf = new RemoteCruiseManagerFactory();
  ICruiseManager ccnetServer = rcmf.GetCruiseManager(ServerAddress);
  ccnetServer.ForceBuild(projectToExecute,"Forced By Programatic Wrapper");
}
```

You can obviously change the second argument to ForceBuild to be the name of your task. It's whats shown under the 'Integration Request' section on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called CCCmd which is included in the CC.NET installer. This is a command-line interface that allows forcing a build remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in the same directory of the ccnet.config file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.exe" -r off -p [Project Name]
```

Comment: The "-p [Project Name]" switch runs the project and shuts down the Cruise Control.NET

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement - to trigger a project from Nant/C# code. With the help of fiddler found out what was happening when we click on 'Force Build' on the Project's web dashboard.

You can send this URL to the build server. Do note the parameters in URL"ForceBuild=Force".

```
http://your-build-server/ccnet/server/local/project/your-project-name/ViewProjectReport.aspx?ForceBuild=Force
```

The "local" in the URL could vary depending on your configuration. For that, first try to fetch project report from CCTray and see what is the URL of your Cruise Control.NET project. Based on the URL modify it to trigger the project.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting the problem? Set up a new CCNET project that has a PowerShell task and a ForceBuild publisher which triggers the original project:

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="OriginalProject">
    <!-- ... -->
  </project name="NewProject">
  <project>
    <tasks>
      <powershell>
        <script>CreateDatabase.ps</script>
        <!-- ... -->
      </powershell>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
      <forcebuild>
        <project>OriginalProject</project>
      </forcebuild>
    </publishers>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

In case you want to run the original project only if `powershell` task went through without any errors just move the `forcebuild` block from the `publishers` to the `tasks` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger directly by submitting a HTTP post. No need to create a separate URL or URL trigger. If Powershell is an option, this works for us (note that our builds have parameters which ccnet prefixes with "param_" in the post variable names, you can omit or tailor the parameters with this prefix for your needs):

```
function Build-CCNetProject {
    param(
        [string] $hostname,
        [string] $server,
        [string] $username,
        [string] $password,
        [string] $project,
        [string] $param_environment,
        [string] $param_build_version,
        [string] $param_request_id
    )
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "$password" -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePassword)
    $postParams = @{projectName="$project";serverName="$server";ForceBuild='Force';param_environment="$param_environment";param_build_version="$param_build_version";param_request_id="param_request_id";submit='Build'}
    $postUrl = "http://{0}/ccnet/server/{1}/project/{2}/ViewProjectReport.aspx" -f $hostname, $server, $project
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $postUrl -Method POST -Body $postParams -Credential $credential
}
# Usage:
Build-CCNetProject -hostname "teamcity" -server "somehost" -username "foo\bar" -password "baz" -project "awesome-app" -param_environment "uat" -param_build_version "1.0.1.123" -param_request_id "1"
```